# TypeError: Cannot read property 'revenue' of undefined

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get some data from the array and show it by using *ngFor in html. Console shows me an error. I can't get any information from ts file in my project It looks like something is wrong and I need some help. What do I missing angular is something new for me.

ts file

```
export class AppComponent  {


   public data =
        [
            {'revenue': {'actual': '123', 'change': '25 '},},

            {'revenue': {'actual': '23 ', 'change': '23 '},},

            {'revenue': {'actual': '43 ', 'change': '12 '},},

        ];


    @Input() public item;
    public record = 0;
    ngOnChanges() {
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }



    public toggle(): void {
      this.record = this.record >= this.item.length - 1 ? 0 : this.record + 1;
  }


}
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
   <div (click)="toggle()">
   <h4>Revenue</h4>
                  <p>Actual {{item['data']['revenue']['actual']}} $<br>
                    Change {{item['data']['revenue']['change']}} %</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by giving the correct stackblitz link, the one giving access to your code, and also make that stackblitz work, just copy-pasting your code in it doesn't make it a [mcve].

Comment: Just remove `['data']` in the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

```
{{item['revenue']['actual']}}
```

or easier

```
{{item.revenue.actual}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works on my example (i can see data in div)  but another step for me is to use it in another component. So I create something like this in html file ```<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <swiper #swiper [config]="swiperconfig">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
              <app-ds-widget-component
                      #card
                      [data]="{data: item}"

              ></app-ds-widget-component>

          </div>
      </ng-container>

  </swiper>

</div>``` And the problems start all ower again